# Java Prepared statement error table not found

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, talend

I've got a problem with a data migration job build with Talend Open Studio for Data Integration. Talend open studio generates java classes. Im migration from one mysql table to another.

The statement:

```
    String insert_tMysqlOutput_1 = "INSERT INTO `"
                    + "workitem"
                    + "` (`name`,`type`,`budgetHours`,`deadline`,`dateStart`,`dateEnd`,`dateCreated`,`projectId`,`parentWorkItem`,`description`,`dateUpdated`,`companyId`,`state`,`reporterId`,`assigneeId`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

            java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 = conn_tMysqlOutput_1
                    .prepareStatement(insert_tMysqlOutput_1);
```

The error:

```
Exception in component tMysqlOutput_1 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dashboard.work_item' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2327)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2312)
at dashboard_new.copy_of_workitem_2_0.Copy_of_workitem.tMysqlInput_1Process(Copy_of_workitem.java:3677)
at dashboard_new.copy_of_workitem_2_0.Copy_of_workitem.tMysqlConnection_2Process(Copy_of_workitem.java:1109)
at dashboard_new.copy_of_workitem_2_0.Copy_of_workitem.runJobInTOS(Copy_of_workitem.java:7370)
at dashboard_new.copy_of_workitem_2_0.Copy_of_workitem.main(Copy_of_workitem.java:7069)
```

Table structure (EDIT #1)

```sql
CREATE TABLE  `dashboard`.`workitem` (
`workItemId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`projectId` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`companyId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`budgetHours` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`deadline` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`dateStart` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`dateEnd` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`parentWorkItem` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text,
`state` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`reporterId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`assigneeId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`dateCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`dateUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`newColumn` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`workItemId`),
KEY `fk_project_id_idx` (`projectId`),
KEY `fk_parent_work_item_idx` (`parentWorkItem`),
KEY `fk_workitem_company1_idx` (`companyId`),
KEY `fk_workitem_name` (`name`),
KEY `fk_workitem_assignee` (`assigneeId`),
KEY `fk_workitem_reporter` (`reporterId`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_workitem_company1` FOREIGN KEY (`companyId`) REFERENCES `company`    (`companyId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2461 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The strange thing is.. `work_item` is not found in the code.. so i think there must by some caching of the statement but have no idea where..

EDIT #1:
And when i add a field into the query that does not exist inside the table then i get an error field not found.. so somehow check if the fields do exists.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely, your code did not compile, and you are running an older version of the code that used to reference `work_item` instead of `workitem`.

Comment: provide table structure in which u r inserting records..

Comment: Kindly Check your database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is accessing `work_item`, but the table's name is `workitem`.

Perhaps there is a trigger on the table that has a coding error in it.
Or perhaps you have not posted the latest versions.

Comment: So stupid, indeed i have a trigger, the tablename before was work_item so when i changed the tablename i didn't change te trigger Thanks! :)

Comment: no no no  its not your answer its nipun's answer please delete your answer..for honesty